# How to handle multiple buttons in a custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell which has 2 buttons (for incrementing and decrementing) and a count label in it. What I want to achieve is to update countLabel appropriately when subtractButton or addButton is tapped.

My custom cell class:

```
class ItemOptionCell: UITableViewCell {

    private var count = 0
    
    private var countLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = "0"
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        return label
    }()

    private let subtractButton: UIButton = {
        let subButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        subButton.setTitle("-", for: .normal)
        subButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(decreaseItemCount), for: .touchUpInside)
        return subButton
    }()
    
    private let addButton: UIButton = {
        let addButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        addButton.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(increaseItemCount), for: .touchUpInside)
        return addButton
    }()

// contains subtract, add buttons and item count
    private var operationsStackView = UIStackView()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        backgroundColor = .white
        
        configureOperationsStackView()
    }

    func set(itemOption: ItemOption) {
        itemLabel.text = itemOption.title
    }

private func configureOperationsStackView() {
        addSubview(operationsStackView)
        
        // code for autolayout     
    }

    @objc private func decreaseItemCount() {
        if count > 0 {
            count -= 1
        }
        
        updateCountLabel()
    }
    
    
    @objc private func increaseItemCount() {
        count += 1
        updateCountLabel()
    }
    
    private func updateCountLabel() {
        countLabel.text = String(count)
    }
```

Part of ViewController for handling table view delegates:

```
extension ItemOptionsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Header #1"
        label.backgroundColor = .orange
        return label
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return options.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return options[section].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId) as! ItemOptionCell
        let option = options[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.set(itemOption: ItemOption(title: option))
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

All the forums I looked up only describe how to handle single buttons.

P.s. I read about assigning tags to buttons but found out that it's not a recommended way as when row count changes managing tags becomes problematic. Therefore, if possible, recommend a way with delegates or closures.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about tags.
Create gesture recognisers in your cellForRowAt and assign them to the buttons:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
...
//Create gesture
//Create two of these: one will be for the add button and one for the minus one. Attach to eachh gesture a different function.
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
//Add the two different gestures to both of the buttons
cell.myButton.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
...
}
//Create two of these: one to add and one to subtract
 @objc func tapped(){
        print("ok")
//Perform your action here
    }
```

Plus, when it comes to adding the buttons in the tableViewCell custom class, call `contentView.addSubview(myButton)` instead of `addSubview(myButton)`.

Oh and obviously, remove all the stuff in your custom class where you add targets to buttons and stuff like that, only create and add the objects to the cell as I said before.

Edit:

Set your buttons as follows:

```swift
//Do this for both buttons
private let subtractButton: UIButton = {
        let subButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        subButton.setTitle("-", for: .normal)
        return subButton
    }()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how can I distinguish which cell was tapped?

Comment: You have to create two gestures, two functions and you have to attach them to the respective buttons. So you'll have addTap (gesture) and addTapped() (objc func) and you'll call something like cell.addButton.addGestureRecognizer(addTap) and you'll do the same with the minus button.

Comment: You'll have to add the gesture to the button, not to the cell! Furthermore, in your class you only have to create the button outlets and add them to the cell, I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean

Comment: Thanks for the update but you got me wrong. What you suggested worked and the cells registered taps. However, when I press a button in a certain cell, a different cell gets modified.

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate for this purpose

```swift
protocol ItemOptionCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didDecreaseItemTapped(in cell: ItemOptionCell)
    func didIncreaseItemCount(in cell: ItemOptionCell)
}

class ItemOptionCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delagate: ItemOptionCellDelegate?
    ...

    private func decreaseItemCount() {
        delegate?.didDecreaseItemTapped(in: self)
    }
    
    
    private func increaseItemCount() {
        delegate?.didIncreaseItemCount(in: self)
    }
```

in your ViewController

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId) as! ItemOptionCell
        let option = options[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.set(itemOption: ItemOption(title: option))
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.countLabel.text = //some value
        
        return cell
    }

extension ItemOptionsViewController: ItemOptionCellDelegate {
    
    func didDecreaseItemTapped(in cell: ItemOptionCell) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
        let option = options[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        //do some stuff with your data, then reload table and set need value for count label. 
    }

    func didIncreaseItemCount(in cell: ItemOptionCell) { ... }
```

Also, **DON'T** update `countLabel` inside cell implementation, basically you have to set value count from your model, for example in ViewController in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` func (in case you use MVC approach)

Comment: Thanks. But I think I am doing something wrong as it's not doing anything.